# Double precision address cast

Tags: c, double, precision

I see a code on the internet and can print a meaningful string, but didn't understand how it works, could anyone explain the logics? Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
double x = 6.55538260547163850123456789E-260, y;
int main(){return(*(char*)&x?x*=y=x,main():printf((char*)&y));}
```

**Update:**

I've already cleaned the code into

```
#include <stdio.h>
double x = 6.55538260547163850123456789E-260, y;
int main(){
  if (*(char*)&x) {
    y = x;
    x *= y;
    main();
  } else {
    printf((char*)&y);
  }
}
```

But still don't know how `(char*)&y` can become a meaningful string, I thought that was about double precision or address cast, so that's the title

**Update II:**

I think the core code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
double x = 6.55538260547163850123456789E-260, y;
int main(){
  y = x;
  printf((char*)&y);
}
```

But the address cast is still so weird.

Comment: It's 'clever code', (ie. a mess).  Split it up, clean it up.

Comment: @MartinJames I've cleaned the code, and that's why the title is. But I still don't know the address cast or something, do you know that?

Comment: @Asoul Who has the time to read his mess, intentionally written in the single line. Useless. If you want to know - sort it yourself. Waste your own time,

Comment: @PeterJ I've cleaned it in the update, but I still don't know the address cast or something, do you know that?

Comment: it is an UB. Debug it. Step over it, and you will know. It will recurse until first byte of the physical representation of the double in memory is not zero.

Comment: @PeterJ I've separate it to a no recurse version in the update, but still don't know how the address cast work, do you understand it?

Comment: I gave you the answer: Debug it. See how the x is presented in the memory, then see where the char * pointer points  after the `&`. See how this pointer is dereferenced. Add some additional variables to store the temporary values. `int main(){
  char *tmpptr = &x; char tmpchar = * tmpptr; if (tmpchar) {` And you will know. That's the best way of learning.

Comment: Many of us were learning C when internet did not exist. We needed to use our own brains instead of someone else's

Comment: @PeterJ it is non-UB on *some* implementations. Casting to `char *` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @ Antti Haapala But it can be. And if it can be and you do not know the implementation you should assume that it is. It is a scholar useless dispute.

Comment: @Asoul the double is reinterpreted as a char string, as simple as that. The double value was carefully picked so that on *your* platform when written to memory, it would be laid out just like the string `"asoul"`.

Comment: @PeterJ there is nothing undefined on *their* platform, otherwise there wouldn't be nothing to ask about. Please do not confuse "is UB" with "is not strictly conforming."

Comment: @Antti Haapala as a char string? Even with the ending zero? Maybe magically already converted to: "6.55538260547163850123456789E-260"?

Comment: Sorry but what is the "UB" abbreviate for? this abbr is too common to search

Comment: @PeterJ ahha I stand corrected, it *is* UB. Asoul, UB stands for "undefined behavio(u)r".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It reinterprets the bytes of the double value as a string. This will view the bytes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
double x = 6.55538260547163850123456789E-260;
int main(){
    unsigned char *y = (unsigned char *)&x;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(double); i ++) {
        printf("%02hhx %c\n", y[i], y[i]);
    }
}
```

On my computer this spits out

```
61 a
73 s
6f o
75 u
6c l
20  
20  
0a
```

However herein lies a problem - the string is `"asoul  \n"` - but without terminating `\0` - so actually your code *has* undefined behaviour even on my laptop where I got your meaningful message.

Comment: Thanks Antti Haapala, I saw it on the internet but don't know how it works, but I find that I can change the string by change the floating number. Now I think I understand it! Thanks! :)